# Ajax Post JSON with circular reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following JSON

```
"node": {
    "id": "812de6d0-a754-11e7-a7d4-47a3233fb668",
    "name": "123",
    "type": "node",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "d517b899-d211-4896-8eeb-466268ddf2e3",
            "name": "456",
            "type": "node",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "a913ce08-aff7-446b-a996-ba5a14939dd1",
                    "name": "789",
                    "type": "node",
                    "children": [],
                    "parent": "d517b899-d211-4896-8eeb-466268ddf2e3"
                }
            ],
            "parent": "812de6d0-a754-11e7-a7d4-47a3233fb668"
        }
    ],
}
```

which, obviously, has a circular reference on the children attribute. As you may assume, this is a "one-to-many" relationship and my backend is expecting the data in this way.

My question is: is there any way to post the data like this using ajax? I tried [circular-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json) and cycle.js from Douglas Crockford but I got no success. Both libraries are not returning the same object when I restore it.

Ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    url: requestURL,
    type: requestType, // POST 
    data: payload, // variable contains the JSON

    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success!");
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: That is simple JSON and I think you should be able to save it as you normally would any other JSON object. What error do you get?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I getting this error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)

Comment: You can post whatever JSON you like - there's no issue with what you're currently doing. The issue will only arise on the server when whatever model binding you're trying to use creates the circular reference. It's there that you need to amend the logic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my request never gets to the server with this error :-)

Comment: In which case could you add more of your code, which explicitly shows where the error is being generated. I can't see how the AJAX call alone would cause that issue

Comment: Are you using `JSON.stringify( yourJson )` for data?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I tried to stringify but I get the same error msg

Comment: Since json is just a simple string format, it can't really have circular references (it doesn't have references.)  If you made a copy of your object and replaced references with ID's before stringifying thus that it would no longer have circular references, you would no longer have this problem.

Comment: @Marrone I think Mohit was suggesting that a stringify could be _causing_ the error, not that you should try it. Somewhere you've directly written, or alternatively you're using something which calls $.extend. Ajax doesn't do that, so the problem must be happening before that. Your browser's tools should be able to help you trace source of the error.

Comment: *"which, obviously, has a circular reference on the children attribute"* well, uhm, where? what circular reference? that's just json.

Comment: If I comment that ajax call, I no longer have the problem. Of course, that isn't what I want.

Comment: That suggests you aren't actually sending json then. You're sending query params, and jquery can't convert circular references to a useful param string. Just like JSON.stringify can't.

Comment: @KevinB ok... so how can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: get rid of the circular references.

Comment: @KevinB thanks! Long day, guys... apologies for the dummy question. Just found it... :-) Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it removing the circular references as pointed out by @kevinb